# Creating turtles with OOP in Python with turtle graphics

Tags: python, class, oop, turtle-graphics

I want to take this

```
t=turtle.Turtle()
t.color("white")
t.pensize(2)
t.shape("turtle")
t.speed(0)
```

And make many of them with OOP
, so I tried and it didn't work

```
class turtles:
    def __init__(self, color, pensize, shape, speed):
        self.self = turtle.Turtle()
        self.color = self.("color")
        self.pensize = self.(pensize)
        self.shape = self.("shape")
        self.speed = self.(speed)



t = turtles('blue', '2', 'turtle', '0')
```

Comment: Not familiar with the library but with your first bit of code it seems the lines in __init__ should be:
self.turtle.XYZ = XYZ

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import turtle
class turtles(turtle.Turtle):
    def __init__(self, color, pensize, shape, speed):
        super().__init__(shape)
        self.color(color)
        self.pensize(pensize)
        self.shape(shape)
        self.speed(speed)

t = turtles("blue", 2, "turtle", 0)
t.forward(10)
```

In the first line of the code I put "Turtle" in the parentheses after the class name to tell python that the class inherits from "Turtle". This means that it uses the "Turtle" class as a base, this technique is commonly used to extend or variate on an existing class.

By inheriting from "Turtle", the "self" variable in the functions is an object that inherits from "Turtle". This means you can set the turtle graphics parameters directly through self and not an extra variable.

You can read more about inheritance here:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_inheritance.asp

Comment: Yeah but how do I include turtle name = turtle.Turtle()

Comment: So I need to create a class within a class or something 

Comment: This doesn't work for me as there's a missing `super().__init__()` which leads to error messages like. "`AttributeError: 'turtles' object has no attribute 'screen'`"

Comment: @cdlane Good catch, documentation ignores it though. Included correction as an edit

Comment: @CalebMynhardt I've made some edits to clarify the import. If you just import the turtle library you can reference the class using `turtle.Turtle`. If you replace the import line with `from turtle import *` where `*` means everything, you can omit `turtle.` and just reference the class directly as `Turtle`.

Answer (score 0):

Without OOP you are using the object of `Turtle`, and when you put it in a class, you have to as well. Try:

```
class turtles:
    def __init__(self, color, pensize, shape, speed):
        self.turtle = turtle.Turtle()
        self.turtle.color(color)
        self.turtle.pensize(pensize)
        self.turtle.shape(shape)
        self.turtle.speed(speed)

t = turtles("blue", 2, "turtle", 0)
```

Comment: I think it's assigning the values to "t" so that I can print them instead of running the code in the class and replacing self with "t"

Comment: I didn't understand. did you try what I wrote?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should do what you describe:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

class MyTurtle(Turtle):
    def __init__(self, color, pensize, shape, speed):
        super().__init__(shape)
        self.color(color)
        self.pensize(pensize)
        self.speed(speed)

yertle = MyTurtle('blue', 2, 'turtle', 'fast')
yertle.circle(100)

screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```

The `super().__init__()` invocation is crucial (and Python3 specific, there's another way to do it in Python2) as it sets various properties the turtle needs.